# Flash / Animate: Multiple SWF on iOS?

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, flash

I am working on an app for my work, where I need to bring in several (around 8 to 9) SWFs into an flash file that is being published to an iPhone. I have the flash projects each of these SWFs were created in, but they did not use the timeline at all, instead each are completely made through code.
I was able to load in the SWFs and get them running on the phone, but only through interpretor mode in Flash. The issue with this is it is not reliable and causes massive slow down after extended use.
I know that the other modes support a single secondary SWF with actionscript.

Here is the code I am using to load in each one.

```
        myLoader = new Loader();                     // create a new instance of the Loader class
        var url:URLRequest = new URLRequest("JavierNew/app.swf"); // in this case both SWFs are in the same folder 
        myLoader.load(url);                                     // load the SWF file
        myLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, demoLoaded);
```

Does anyone have any solutions or suggestions for how I can better import these in a better fashion? To my knowledge there is no way to import the swf or the whole project file into the main .Fla, or a way to combine all the .swfs together.

Any help would be appreciated! Thank you so much!

Comment: You can use `[embed]` on each of those SWF so that they are part of the final SWF as one larger file. See if **[this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36733352/2057709)** is helpful about embedding & loading the external SWF files. You want the whole line about `private var emb_SWF` and the loading part is `var my_Swf : MovieClip = new emb_SWF();` etc

Comment: Thank you! Testing it out now. Will this work for iOS though? I vaguely remember that you couldn't embed on iOS?

Comment: You let me know... I've never tested on iOS. I didn't know you can't embed, I'm just aware that you cannot load more external SWF files (animation is ok but not code) after app is published.. An embedded one should become part of the main code anyways & not classed as external loaded. Let me know...

Comment: It unfortunately didn't work. I was able to get the embed to work on desktop but once it was on iOS it just wouldn't load. There is the possibility that I was doing it wrong though. Thanks for your help regardless!