# Adobe Flash: How to join several separate .swf files into one .exe file?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Noob ask:
I have many separate .swf files, they are like stairs..
for example:

menu.swf load scene1.swf

scene1.swf load scene2.swf
and so on...

There is a button in menu.swf to load scene1.swf and there is a button in scene1.swf to load scene2.swf and so on...

*every .swf file has it own code, I use Adobe Flash CS6 and Actionscript 3.0
I use loader to load those .swf file

```
var myLoader:Loader = new Loader();                     
var intro:URLRequest = new URLRequest("Intro.swf");     
myLoader.load(intro);                                   
addChild(myLoader);
```

**My problem:
When I create project on menu.swf to menu.exe... press the button... it can't load any .swf file..** T-T"

**so.. what should I do..?**

here is sample of my project:
https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B7S5VF_EUl_dbEg1WmNCYVBfQTA&usp=sharing

*based on my project Little Red Riding Hood.swf is the main menu. It works fine when I run it with .swf

**Edit:**
This is my full code of the menu, perhaps anyone can help me out.. ^^
*this code works fine when I run it with .swf

```
btnRead.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, read); 
btnPlay.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, read); 

function read(event:MouseEvent):void { 
    var myScene1:Loader = new Loader();                    
    var scene1:URLRequest = new URLRequest("scene1.swf");   
    myScene1.load(scene1);                                  
    addChild(myScene1);  
}

btnAbout.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, about); 

function about(event:MouseEvent):void { 
    gotoAndStop(4); 
}

btnScene.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, scene);
btnScene1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, scene); 

function scene(event:MouseEvent):void { 
    gotoAndStop(5); 
}




import flash.system.fscommand;

btnQuit.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, closeApp);

function closeApp(event:MouseEvent):void {
    fscommand("quit");
}
```

Comment: Did you try to `embed` the other SWFs in your AS3 code? then a click loads the embed data instead a file on disk. See **[this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36733352/2057709)** for a clue on embedding and loading to stage the SWF files. For a test... Put such code in **Menu** SWF and embed a **Scene1.swf** (it will export bigger a Menu SWF since it contains other SWF data inside itself). Now your button's click function should simply declare a var and `addChild` the embeded Scene1.

Comment: @VC.One I'm sorry but I don't get it where I should put that `embed` code..

Comment: @VC.One: hehehe... XD

Comment: Try it before you do the top event listeners. Also remove any `public` or `private` since your code is on timeline. Try like `[Embed(source="scene1.swf")] var SWF_scene1 : Class;` then later you say `var my_Swf : MovieClip = new SWF_scene1();` and when ready to display just use `addChild(my_Swf);`...

Comment: @VC.One yaay... it works!! but yeah the file is much much much bigger... is there any way to reduce it...? I just reach scene2 and it is already 108MB. There is 17 scenes remain, I can't imagine how much it will be..

Comment: I'm not sure. Only you knows what you're doing to end up with big files... Are you making a game? Did you import every asset (sound, images) into each SWF? Maybe try keeping assets in compressed formats like jpg & mp3 and load (decompress) the media files as needed by code.

Comment: @VC.One.. No i'm not making game, it is just interactive story... yes I import all assets into each .swf....  Isn't there any method to merge those swf files more efficiently..?

Comment: I just reach scene3 and now it is 226MB.. T-T...

Comment: There is no such thing as _"...merge those swf files more efficiently"_. Your SWF should just have only code for handlng the interactions and for loading of any external images or sounds **as they are needed** on screen... Those imported things should be loaded by code (then you have a small SWF of instruction code only)

Comment: @VC.One LOL... XD hahaha... I hate code.. well... I'll try to copy and paste those frame into one .fla anyway I think it 'could be' (perhaps not, who know) more efficient than merging .swf files... Thank you for those tips :D

Comment: Why did you ever think "**interactive** story" if you hate to write code??? Anyways your files are big cos the things you import make the final size big. A 5mb jpeg gives you a 5mb SWF... Or you can make a small 2kb SWF with lines of code to load and display that 5mb jpeg. Small SWF is the result, but the 5mb must be placed together with SWF. No worries about tips, you'll find a suitable solution for you in the end...

Comment: @VC.One Because I think Interactive story is easier than any other programming, my code above is very simple isn't ^-^...Did you try the sample project on that link..? What do you think..? ^-^