# Publish AS3 along with my audio files

Tags: actionscript-3

Hi im just thinking if it is possible to include my audio files when publish my swf file to my phone? Here is my code, i'm using an audio file that is from my desktop, but after publishing it in my phone, the audio files are not found. So is it possible to publish my swf file with my audio files?

```
 var s: Sound = new Sound();
 var c: SoundChannel = new SoundChannel();
 s.load(new URLRequest('Humble.mp3'));
```

Comment: You should've explained what do you do to "publish" and what tool do you use: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: You will need to include the mp3 file in your build. This can be done somewhere in the Build settings / package contents. What program are you using ? If you will play this sound everytime (not on click or some other request) it might be easier that you embed it in your code and it will be compiled straight into your swf. No need to include it into the build or load it

Comment: Try to `embed` your mp3 files by code then they'll become part of output file. See if this [**Answer**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36723309/embedding-binary-data-into-flash-applications/36733352#36733352) for tips. Look at that `emb_MP3` variable and how it's used in that code sample.)

Comment: Thank you guys! It is now solved!