# Link to .swf and Compile into .apk

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash, hyperlink, flash-cs6

Alright, for the previous question I asked how do I make .AS3 Script but doesn't seems to have any answer. So, now I'm really struggle with this thing. I'm not so good in english, pardon me. I don't know how do I link .swf file in my Adobe Flash project and compile it as .apk . Let me explain.

Explaination .

I have Adobe Flash Project which is the Main Menu, and I want to link each button, to different .Swf. And If I compile the project into .apk does all the button work?

Thankyou community.

Comment: It is unclear what "link" is. In AS3 buttons are interactive objects that produce all kinds of mouse events. There are no "links" in buttons, which means these "links" are something that you scripted. No one else knows what are they. You didn't care to explain. Of course no one answers.

Comment: If by "Link" you mean button clicks then yes, the click events will work on mobile in the same way. You will need to include your "different swfs" into the apk build though

Comment: Look into using AS3's `embed` option to include the SWFs as part of the APK. The embedded SWF(s) are classed as a movieClip by rest of your AS3. So to _"load"_ the swf you actually just _"addChild"_ it. See this older [**Answer**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36723309/embedding-binary-data-into-flash-applications/36733352#36733352) for tips. Look at that `emb_SWF` variable and how it's used in that code sample.

Comment: by include you mean I have to embed it before I convert it into apk? Do you know how do I embed my .swf file into my project? @Philarmon

Comment: @Organis Yeah my bad. I was really bad in english thats why no one understand me.