# Air ios imported swf (no code) suddenly starts giving 'Uncompiled AS' error

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, flash, air, flash-builder

I'm building an iOS app with FlashBuilder 4.7 and Air SDK 25.0. The app has code which installs fonts via an external SWF imported at runtime (no code in external SWF, just fonts). Imported file has been working for months but now throws below error in debugger on device :

> 'Uncompiled ActionsScript'

I have gone back through previous builds and some that had been working fine suddenly throw error on the swf file. Other old builds will work importing the same swf, but after running a build which fails, the working one will start throwing error!

Anyone else struck a problem like this?
I recently upgraded from SDK 22 to 25, but the problem appeared some time after that. Only significant change was running a dodgy zip ANE that crashed the debug. I've removed the ANE, but I suspect something may have been corrupted somewhere.

- I've tried resetting FlashBuilder settings by deleting `.metadata` folder in workspace.
- Tried Cleaning the projects, tried duplicating projects, tried re-publishing the swf to import.

Can't work out why some builds don't work and others do, but then stop working with no changes to the project. I feel sure there is a fix that will suddenly make all of the builds work again...

Any suggestions anyone?

Comment: How are you importing the font swf? is it a URLrequest to some web server? What happens if you `embed` the font swf within your own main app so the two things get compiled together as one unit? Also why have fonts in separate SWF?

Comment: The app invokes a file that contains the swf with fonts so a particular 'project' can use those fonts to match the project's style. Fonts are included in the fla file and given a classname with 'export for Actionscript' but no code. This system has been working in my app for months, but now all builds report the swf as containing ABC code.

Comment: `Uncompiled ActionScript` is an Apple issue, Things might have recently changed on the iOS side (ie: any externally loaded swf might be deemed unsafe nowadays). _"The app invokes a file that contains the swf"_ so skip file and just `embed` this font swf directly into your app and then use it like any other imported class. See this [**Answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36733352/2057709) if unfamiliar with swf embedding by code. Can't font file just be applied in your app before compiling? I mean why in a separate FLA to make extra swf?, all this could be in your own main app..

Comment: Thanks VCOne. The intention is to load ANY font needed for a project when loaded, and format text with css, then when a new project is opened, uninstalls old fonts and loads the new fonts for the new project. Can't embed every font into the app. Worked great! The problem is that ios seems to have suddenly blocked swf's with fonts - hmm, maybe to stop people loading fonts with swfs ;)

Answer (score 0):

I found my problem. 
It appears I have previously been using only the 'Fast' packaging method to test app on ios device, which works. 
When set to 'Standard' (Build) packaging to test on device it causes the swf (with embedded fonts) imported at runtime as having 'uncompiled actionscript'.
This answers my original query, but if anyone has a work-around, or alternate method of importing fonts at runtime, I'd be very happy to hear!